# How do I get these divs to appear side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get these 3 divs to appear side-by-side rather than stacked on top of each other. Ideally it would just look like "< 1 >", all on the same line. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="controls-outer">
    <div id="back-button">&laquo;</div>
    <div id="current-slide">1</div>
    <div id="forward-button">&raquo;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#controls-outer{
    margin:auto;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:black;
}

#back-button{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#forward-button{
    cursor:pointer;    
}

#current-slide{

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9xzr24sy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your css file:

```
   #back-button, #current-slide, #forward-button {
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9xzr24sy/1/

`display:inline-block` makes the `div` elements display inline but with their height and width also taken into account.

Comment: Thank you, simple solution and it works great! Will mark as solved asap.

Comment: @matthew thanks glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You could also float the div's to the left

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 1):

for non-block elements that only contain one character or one word like in your case, you could use `<span>` instead of `<div>` elements - these are inline elements and will remain on one line.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this CSS which depends on `display`:

```
#controls-outer{
        margin:auto;
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color:black;
        display: table-row;
    }

    #back-button{
        cursor:pointer;
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;

    }
    #forward-button{
        cursor:pointer; 
         display:table-cell;
         vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #current-slide{
         display:table-cell;
    }
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9xzr24sy/2/)